# Im trying to make custom buttons for a GUI with wxwidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Im trying to make a simple GUI with 2 custom buttons. The 2 buttons are made as Panels and I can't seem to make the panels switch color when I press on them. At the moment they give the same output when I press them but that has to change but im not sure how at the moment either.

This is the code and if you have an idea of how I could fix my problem I would love your input :D.

**PS: There are multiple #Include <wx/wx.h> in the code and so on because I make .h files for my classes !**

Image of GUI the code gives:
[image]

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

class MyPanel : public wxPanel {

    bool pressedDown;
    wxString text;


    public:
    MyPanel(wxWindow *parent, wxString text);

    void paintEvent(wxPaintEvent & evt);
    void paintNow();
        
    void render(wxDC& dc);
        
    // some useful events
    
    void mouseDown(wxMouseEvent& event);
    void mouseReleased(wxMouseEvent& event);
    void mouseLeftWindow(wxMouseEvent& event);
        
    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()


}; 

#include "Panels.h"
#include <iostream>

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyPanel,wxWindow)

    EVT_LEFT_DOWN(MyPanel::mouseDown)
    EVT_LEFT_UP(MyPanel::mouseReleased)
    EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW(MyPanel::mouseLeftWindow)
    

    // catch paint events
    EVT_PAINT(MyPanel::paintEvent)

END_EVENT_TABLE()

MyPanel::MyPanel(wxWindow *parent, wxString text) : wxPanel(parent, wxID_ANY){
    this->text = text;
    pressedDown = false;
}

void MyPanel::paintEvent(wxPaintEvent & evt)
{
    // depending on your system you may need to look at double-buffered dcs
    wxPaintDC dc(this);
    render(dc);
}

void MyPanel::paintNow()
{
    // depending on your system you may need to look at double-buffered dcs
    wxClientDC dc(this);
    render(dc);
}

void MyPanel::render(wxDC&  dc)
{
    if (pressedDown)
        dc.SetBrush( *wxRED_BRUSH );
        else
        dc.SetBrush( *wxGREY_BRUSH );
    
    dc.DrawText( text, 20, 15 );
}

void MyPanel::mouseDown(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    pressedDown = true;
    paintNow();
}

void MyPanel::mouseReleased(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    pressedDown = false;
    paintNow();

    std::cout << "Pressed" << std::endl;
}
void MyPanel::mouseLeftWindow(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    if (pressedDown)
    {
        pressedDown = false;
        paintNow();
    }
}

#include <wx/wx.h>

class AppFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
   AppFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint &pos, const wxSize &size);

};

#include <wx/wx.h>
#include "AppFrame.h"
#include "Panels.h"

MyPanel* m_btn_1;
MyPanel* m_btn_2;


AppFrame::AppFrame(const wxString &title, const wxPoint &pos, const wxSize &size)
: wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size) {

    wxInitAllImageHandlers();
    
    m_btn_1 = new MyPanel( this, wxT("PickUp") );
    m_btn_1->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(100, 100, 200));

    m_btn_2 = new MyPanel( this, wxT("PlaceDown") );
    m_btn_2->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(100, 200, 100));

    wxBoxSizer *sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    sizer->Add(m_btn_1, 1, wxEXPAND | wxLEFT | wxTOP | wxRIGHT, 10);
    sizer->Add(m_btn_2, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 10);

    this->SetSizerAndFit(sizer);
Centre();
}

#include <wx/wx.h>

class App : public wxApp
{
public:
   virtual bool OnInit();
};
 
// This defines the equivalent of main() for the current platform.
DECLARE_APP(App);

#include "main.h"
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include "AppFrame.h"

IMPLEMENT_APP(App)

bool App::OnInit(){
    AppFrame *frame = new AppFrame("Frame",wxDefaultPosition,wxDefaultSize);
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to make the buttons as custom panels?  Can you not just use the builtin button type and change the background color in response to a click?

Comment: Im very new at this and im just trying things out from looking at eksampels and so I don't know what is possible. If you have an example, I would love to see it. Im kinda trying to make something I have thought out in my mind. Imma uploade an image of what the code gives when I compile :D.

Comment: There are quite a lot of wxWidgets examples out there.  The basic wxButton type has a SetBackgroundColor, SetForegroundColor, and SetLabel method.  That may be all you need.  https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_button.html

Comment: BTW, a very similar post to what you are trying to accomplish here on the wxWidgets forum: https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=49199

Comment: I don't see how I can customise a wxButton into something like what I made (see image), can you?

Comment: @user13170084, what is the reason you can't use wxButton for it? I.e. - what functionality from wxButton you don't want and that exist inside regular wxPanel?

Comment: @Igor if i use wxButton instead, how would i change the default size on the button and color and so on? i cant find any documentation on that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 big problems in this code:

1. You must not use `wxClientDC` at all, see the note in [its documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.2/classwx_client_d_c.html). Just call `Refresh()` instead to redraw the window.
2. You must [capture the mouse](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.2/classwx_window.html#a5c72c6260a73ef77bb0b1f7ec85fcfef) when reacting to mouse down events as otherwise you're going to have problems if the user presses the button inside the window and releases it outside of it (without the capture you won't get the latter event at all).

There might be other problems I didn't notice, but you need to fix at least these ones.